# redirect when login is successful using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, fetch-api

I need to make a redirection to another page (component) when user validates successfully with email/password, otherwise, show a warning message on a div that says email or password not correct.

This is my code:

```
 constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // name: "",
          cnx_mail: '',
          cnx_pwd: '',
          joinByEmail: '',
          items: [],
          token : '',
          redirectToReferrer:false,
          errors: {},

          formErrors: {cnx_mail: '', cnx_pwd: ''},
          emailValid: false,
          passwordValid: false,
          formValid: false
        }
         this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

     handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                  },
                body: JSON.stringify ({
                    email: this.state.cnx_mail,
                    password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
                  })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                localStorage.setItem('toktok', json.result);
                console.log(json[0].role);
//i have to verify email/password bedore redirection
                window.location.href="/accounts";
            }); 
          }
```

And this is my form in render():

```
<form className="demoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate  encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                <div className="alreadysubscribed-input">
                                    <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_mail)}`}>
                                        <input type="email" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_mail"
                                            value={this.state.cnx_mail}
                                            id="cnx_mail"
                                            onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_mail} />
                                            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_mail">Email</label>
                                            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>                                  
                                    </div>

                                    <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_pwd)}`}>
                                        <input type="password" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_pwd"
                                            value={this.state.cnx_pwd}
                                            id="cnx_pwd"
                                            onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_pwd} />
                                            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_pwd">Mot de passe</label>
                                            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />

                                <div className="btn-cnx">
                                    {/* <span className="mas">Se connecter</span> */}
                                    <button className="fatb-btn bubbly-button btn-anim3 w100p" type="submit"  name="cnx_btn" disabled={!this.state.formValid}>se connecter</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

i need to verify if the role == "admin" then redirect to /accounts, otherwise display a warning msg in a div for example.

this is the structure of my data :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "result": [
        {
            "dateCreation": "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z",
            "resetpasswordtoken": null,
            "resetpasswordexpires": null,
            "role": "admin",
            "enable": true,
            "_id": "5d9e67772682971c1fc3711c",
            "email": "meachemlal@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$HqEMSkaWBZ..BFvSpxliUu/02vWodvxYoFZMaYUU5ZsBeqeZB4jLu",
            "tickets": [],
            "gains": [],
            "__v": 0,
            "nom": "ACHEMLAL",
            "prenom": "MERYEM",
            "tel": "+33619562721"
        },
        {
            "dateCreation": "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z",
            "resetpasswordtoken": null,
            "resetpasswordexpires": null,
            "role": "admin",
            "enable": true,
            "_id": "5d9e677e2682971c1fc3711d",
            "email": "mika.achemlal@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$Bg4nOrNMzc.b/JBNKNiRP.BiMd/.h4CHKiy0nvV/uim0d3VwHl9iq",
            "tickets": [],
            "gains": [],
            "__v": 0
        },
    ........
```

Comment: Which routing library are you using? If you are using react-router you can look here of how to redirect to another page upon successful login. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: please mention which library you are using to set routes.

Comment: Yes, it's react-router

Comment: sorry it's not really clear for me the link :/
i need to check if the mail/password are good

Answer (score 4):

For redirect page, you can write code `window.location.href`, as I describe below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const token =  localStorage.getItem('toktok');
    fetch(`${API}/api/accounts`,{
        headers :{
            'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
        }
    })
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ items: data.result });
        window.location.href="/nextpageurl";
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error : ",err);
    });
 }
```

And
Before redirect page validation:-

```
  import { AvForm,AvField} from 'availity-reactstrap-validation';
    <AvForm onValidSubmit={this.onSubmit} name="login" className="app_start_form">
      <div className="form-group">
       <span className="icon"><img src={email} alt="" /></span> 
        <AvField type="text" ng-model="user.Email" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Email/Mobile No.*" 
                           validate={{
                            pattern: { value: /^((([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,}))|([0-9]{9,}))\w+$/, errorMessage: 'Please enter valid emailid or mobile no' },
                            required: { value: true, errorMessage: "Email or Mobile No. is required" },
                            maxLength: { value: isMobile, errorMessage: 'Mobile No. must be maximum '+isMobile+' digits' }
                          }} />
 <AvField type="password" name="password" autoFocus value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Password *" 
                           validate={{
                            required: { value: true, errorMessage: "Password is required" },
                            pattern: { value:/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/, errorMessage: 'Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit' },
                            minLength: { value: 8, errorMessage: 'Password must be at least 8 characters' },
                            maxLength: { value: 20, errorMessage: 'Password not more then 20 characters' }
                          }} /> 
                        </div>

       <div className="sec_btn loginbtn_ind">
         <button type="submit" className="btn blue_btn">SIGN IN</button>
        </div>
     </AvForm>
```

Comment: But how can i check if the password and email are correct before redirect please?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a library for your routing needs. Some of the popular ones are react-router, reach-router [etc](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html). React philosophically, is not opinionated about which router is used nor does it ship with one.

Assuming: You are using react-router

in .then

```
.then(data => {
    this.setState({ items: data.result });
    this.props.history.push('/nextpage');        
})
```

Comment: Hey, can i use  that without library ?

Comment: If you use react-router than yes. Take a look here https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/redirect-on-login-and-logout.html

Comment: You will have to use a library for your routing needs. Some of the popular ones are react-router, reach-router etc. React philosophically, is not opinionated about which router is used nor does it ship with one.

Answer (score 0):

try using `history.push`

like this:
 this.props.history.push('/RedirectTargetComponent');